# How to generate bad files from file in unix without closing double quotes

Tags: file, unix, double-quotes

I have file that has data like -  "A","BVC","DSDFGS",FDG34" , as you can see last data does not have starting double quotes. I want to create a bad file for those records without staring or ending double quotes and process rest of the file.

Any idea would be helpful - how to implement this in unix.

Answer (score 1):

You want a regular expression that only matches the good lines.
A good line will have at least one field in double quotes (I skip empty lines).
A field can be seen as a double quote, some (0 or more) characters without double quotes and a new double quote.
When a line has more than 1 field, all fields are followed by an `,` except the last one.
Use `grep` to skip these correct lines from the file.

```
grep -Ev '^("[^"]*",)+("[^"]*")$' inputfile > badfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you know the number of quote characters in
a good line beforehand
(which is `8` in your case). You can use `awk` to split lines into columns using
a `"` character as a separator  and print only those which have less than `8` "`'s.

```
awk -F\" '{if(NF - 1 < 8){print $0}}' inputfile > badfile
```